# $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ with more than one element and $A/ \{a\}$ is compact for a fixed $a\in A$

Tags: general-topology

Question is :

Suppose $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ with more than one element and $A/ \{a\}$ is compact for a fixed $a\in A$ then

- $A$ is compact
- Every subset of $A$ must be compact
- $A$ must be finite
- $A$ is disconnected

Only compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ I can think of are finite union of closed intervals and finite sets.

Take a  finite union of closed intervals, If i remove one element for that I would end up with something which contains $[a,b)$  and this would be not compact so should be the whole set.

So, First option is wrong i.e., $A$ is not compact.

I can not say anything about second and fourth option but third option is possible I guess.

Please help me to see this in detail..

Comment: No, your property is false, consider $A=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ and $a=2$

Comment: Really for a fixed $a\in A$, or for each $a\in A$?

Comment: For the first: $A=\{a\}\cup(A\setminus\{a\})$.

Comment: @Praphulla Koushik : the first bullet point is true because the union of two compact sets is compact.

Comment: @StefanSmith : Good point.. :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover for $A$. This is also an open cover for $A\setminus\{a\}$. As this is compact, there exists a finite subcover. Together with one $U_i$ with $a\in U_i$ we obtain a finite subcover for $A$. Hence, yes, $A$ is compact.
2. No. Consider $A=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$, which has the noncompact subset $(0,1)$.
3. No. Consider $A=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ again, which is infinite.
4. Yes. Consider the open cover $$A\setminus\{a\}\subseteq\bigcup_{r>0}(\mathbb R\setminus[a-r,a+r]).$$
   By compactness there is a finite subcover, which boils down to $A\setminus\{a\}\subseteq \mathbb R\setminus[a-r,a+r]$ for some $r>0$. Thus $a$ is an isoloated point of $A$ and $A$ is disconnected.

Comment: Perfect.... Thank you :)

Comment: Another way to see that $a$ is isolated in $A$: if not, there would be a sequence $(x_n)$ from $A\setminus\{a\}$ that converged to $a$. This sequence would contradict sequential compactness of $A\setminus \{a\}$.

Comment: How $a$ being isolated point implies $A$ disconnected? Can you explain a bit more to me?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

The set $\;[0,1]\cup\{2\}\;$ already deals with options 2,3,4...

Option 1 is true, otherwise there exists $\;\{a_n\}\subset A\;$ s.t. that no subsequence of it converges in $\;A\;$, so...

Comment: Yes Yes... I got it :) Thank you :)